# Change SnowFlake account locator to account name

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

According to this article (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-account-identifier.html#), SnowFlake has two different ways for account IDs:

1. Account name - created by me, for example, my-company.snowflakecomputing.com
2. Account locator - a more technical name, not as nice and understandable as 1)

Now we are using locator and I don't understand, it is possible to change locator to name or not?

P.S. I read, that account locator can't be changed, but maybe this is only true for changing locator to locator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The account locator can not be renamed/modified once the account is created.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-account-identifier.html#option-2-account-locator-in-a-region

Your account name is the alias for your account locator, and it can be renamed (by support). If you want to connect to your Snowflake account, using the account name, you need to use the orgname-accountname.snowflakecomputing.com format.

Btw, all accounts also have a "random" organization name. Support will tell your organization name or rename it if you request.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to change the account alias and access your account via a new name, if you are using the Organizations-Feature. Now I assume your account is not part of an organization, so we have to use the "Option 2" of the below link (same as yours).

So... no, it is not possible to change, if you created your account on your own through self-service. Only if a Snowflake representative is creating your account, then this person can change to a name.

Docs: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-account-identifier.html

Comment: Marcel, the locator for an account cannot be changed once the account is created.

Comment: Sorry, typo :) I was not that precise and confused "locator" with "name"/"alias". Thanks for the note :-)

Answer (score 0):

[Changing Account Name](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/organizations-manage-accounts.html#changing-account-name):

> **An organization administrator (i.e. a user granted the ORGADMIN role) can use the ALTER ACCOUNT command to rename an account.** For example, the following command renames an account called original_acctname to new_acctname:
>
> ```
> use role orgadmin;
> alter account original_acctname rename to new_acctname;
> ```
>
> **By default, Snowflake allows you to access the renamed account with either the original URL or the URL that contains the new account name.** To prevent access using the old URL, set the optional SAVE_OLD_URL parameter to FALSE when renaming the account. If the account has already been renamed without this parameter, you can still block the old URL by executing the ALTER ACCOUNT new_acctname DROP OLD URL command.